# strlen doesn't work

Tags: php, function

i was just make a simple script, but it don't work.

```
function check_length($string, $min_length, $max_length) {
  $length = strlen($string);
  if(strlen($length) < $min_length || strlen($length) > $max_length)
  { 
    header("Location: /kontakty/blad");
  }
}

check_length($_POST["name"], "3", "45");
check_length($_POST["surname"], "3", "45");
check_length($_POST["group_id"], "1", "11");
```

When i send data to script, the function don't check this.

---

**Edit**: I was do like You wrote and now script don't wanna redirect.

[**Full script**](http://wklej.org/hash/4937e6cdeec/)

Comment: why do you have strlen on $length? remove strlen()

Comment: `$length = strlen($string);` you already calculated length so when you  `strlen($length)` it calculate length of $length not string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a mistake. remove strlen on $length.

```
function check_length($string, $min_length, $max_length) {
      $length = strlen($string);

     if($length < $min_length || $length > $max_length)
     { 
      header("Location: /kontakty/blad");
     }
}
```

Comment: God: I was wrote script like You and the function don't check length. May i show You my full script: http://wklej.org/hash/4937e6cdeec/

Comment: if should check length `die($string)` in function add check what you getting

Comment: @RomanKonopski try removing the quotes around your numbers perhaps? Doubt that is the problem but you might as well rule it out!

Comment: you are sending string not number @InGodITrust is right

Answer (score 3):

Seems you use this script on an unicode'd site (kontakty) and suppose you need to use `mb_strlen` instead `strlen` for this work. Additionally, use `trim`, or "a " gives 2 length in this case.

```
function check_length($string, $min, $max) {
    $length = mb_strlen(trim($string), 'utf-8');
    if ($length < $min || $length > $max) { 
        header('Location: /kontakty/blad');
    }
}
```

If `mb_strlen` doesn't work for you, can use this:

```
function strlen_unicode($str) {
    return count(preg_split(
        '~~u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
}
```

Comment: do you know why my mb_strlen didn't working? i try in my local server and it's working but when I upload mb_strlen and strlen length is same. Please reply if you can. Really appreciate.

Comment: @scramble; you should set internal encoding using `mb_internal_encoding` func at the first.

Comment: Then why in my local server mb_strlen working well but in my hosting it doesn't work well? doesn't it because configuration in my local server?

Answer (score 2):

```
function check_length($string, $min_length, $max_length) {

  $length = strlen($string);  <= calculated once

  if(strlen($length) < $min_length || strlen($length) > $max_length)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^
                                     no need of this it will calculate length of 
                                     $length no string   

  { 
    header("Location: /kontakty/blad");
  }
}
```

try

```
function check_length($string, $min_length, $max_length) {

  if(strlen($string) < $min_length || strlen($string) > $max_length)
  { 
    header("Location: /kontakty/blad");
  }
}
```

[according to the code in your comment link](http://wklej.org/hash/4937e6cdeec/)

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `strlen($length)` with `$length` in the line:

```
if(strlen($length) < $min_length || strlen($length) > $max_length)
```

You are taking the length of the length which make no sense.

Comment: i thin it should be `strlen($string)`